# Laravel access secured and unsecured route

Tags: laravel

I am under Laravel 8.0.
I have a route that is not secure (I still have access to it and that's normal, that's what I want).
The problem is that when I am connected (with Passport) and my token has expired, the route still works even though the token has expired.
I wanted to make a middleware that checks the validity of the token if it exists, but I can't.
How to do it please?
Thank you.

**edited: 2021-09-14 11:28**

I have an appointment scheduling application,

A vuejs web application accessible by all (not secure) ->

A client part accessible only if we have a username and password (secure)

In my API routes (laravel> routes) in my routes / web.php file I have nothing.

In my routes / api.php file I have the code below.

```
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::get('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::get('session', 'AuthController@getSessionId');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
});

/* Secured (client) */

Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {

    // all other routes

    Route::middleware(['check.tenant'])->group(function () {

        Route::resource('structures', 'StructureController')->except(['show']);

    });
});

/* Unsecured (user) */

Route::resource('structures', 'StructureController')->only(['show']);
```

Comment: Have you applied auth middleware of passport on route ?

Comment: Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () { 
precisely no because otherwise I have to send a token all the time.
it will work for the secure part but it will never work on the other

Comment: Checkout this link I think this is what you want: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-passport-aouth-check-when-token-expires

Comment: Thank you. but there is one thing i dont understand, i am having trouble doing something.
In your example, it adds a middleware to check if the token is valid in the secure part, this means that I have to duplicate the route (in auth: api and in the non-secure part). I will post part of my routes

Comment: just apply the example middleware on all of your routes.

Comment: it does not work. user is null

Comment: do you have other ideas ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237086/discussion-between-kaleem-shoukat-and-jeygey).